# what is the difference between curly braces and double quotes for tcl commands

Tags: tcl

what exactly is different when double quotes are used instead of curly braces in tcl commands. For example:

```
regsub "$something" $var1 "$something2" var1
```

vs

```
regsub {$something} $var1 {$something2} var1
```

The question isn't limited to just regsub though. Even when assigning to a variable using `set` I don't really see any difference.

Comment: It's explained in the tutorial; see [this page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl3.html) and [this page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl4.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double quotes and curly braces are used to group words together into one argument. The difference between double quotes and curly braces is that quotes allow substitutions to occur in the group, while curly braces prevent substitutions. This rule applies to command, variable, and backslash substitutions.

Grouping with double quotes vs. braces.

```
set s Hello
=> Hello
puts stdout "The length of $s is [string length $s]."
=> The length of Hello is 5.
puts stdout {The length of $s is [string length $s].}
=> The length of $s is [string length $s].
```

Here, the Tcl interpreter does variable and command substitution on the second argument to puts. In the third command, substitutions are prevented so the string is printed as-is.

In practice, grouping with curly braces is used when substitutions on the argument must be delayed until a later time (or never done at all). Examples include loops, conditional statements, and procedure declarations. Double quotes are useful in simple cases like the puts command previously shown.

**Reference :** [Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk](http://www.beedub.com/book/2nd/tclintro.doc.html)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the distinction between " " and { } is clear, but under the surface, things can be different from what you would expect.
For example, curly brackets between quotes do not have a special meaning.

If you write:

```
set x "hello"
puts "{$x}"
```

you will get:

```
"{hello}"
```

and

```
string length {$x}
==> 2
string length "{$x}"
==> 7
```

So be careful when to use curly brackets and quotation marks.

You can find a clear and elaborate explanation of the ins and outs of Tcl at:
https://ipenv.com/ins-and-outs-tcltk